# how to setup separated local and remote branches for the first time

Tags: git, github, git-merge

-I have some work in the local repo under the default "master" branch.
-After, I create a new repo on GitHub with 1 commit there, under the default "master" branch. -Now, I am trying to add this remote repo to local by its link.

- In the end, I want all my locally done work **on remote under the master** branch **with all remote and local made commits**, how can I do this?

Comment: Do you care about the commit on GitHub? Is it just a readme file or similar that you can just blow away? If yes, after adding your remote you can just force push your `master` branch.

Answer (score 1):

Merging two separate repositories is not a normal occurrence.  One usually creates a repo somewhere, and then pushes/pulls copies of that repo to/from other places.  The usual thing is to create a repo locally and then at some point push it up to Github, Bitbucket, etc.

If you have two repos that are not yet related, and what you have in the remote repo doesn't have much history (1 commit you say?), then don't try to do anything at all with commits in the remote repo. Rather, just copy the source files themselves into your local repo, doing file merges as needed to get to just what you want to move forward with.  You'll probably start by cloning the remote repo onto your local machine as a second separate repo.  Once you've added/updated all the files in your original local repo from the copy of the remote repo, then do a `git add` of all of the files you've brought over, either updates to existing files or new files. Then do a `git commit`.

So merging the two source trees will consist of creating one new commit on your local repo.  Once you have done all of this, you can then do a `git push` to push a copy of your local repo up to Github.  Once you know everything is good, you can just delete all copies of the originally remote-only repo, both on your local box and on Github.